# which layout would be the best solution?

Tags: java, android, layout, android-layout

I am trying to create a layout that can fits my situation where I will need to have a layout that keeps the views like imageview or textview or probably a combination of a few. while on the top right of it, i will need to have two buttons on top.

However, this layout has to be dynamic where I can select whether if I want to show the buttons or not. How should I go about it?

Comment: showing your layout(prototype) pictorially will get you more answers.

Answer (score 0):

You can use any layout you want really, although it sounds like a horizontal LinearLayout would fit your situation the best.

You can then control visibility of individual elements via `setVisibility(View.GONE)` and `setVisibility(View.VISIBLE)`, or simply through `addView`.